# angularjs templates and css from directive folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know how attach css and templates url in a angularjs directive.

For example, with templates i have this

```
    /***   myDirectives   ***/
    angular.module('myDirectives', [])

        .directive('webcams', function($sce, $http, $templateCache, $compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<div class="included" ng-include src="getTemplateUrl();"></div>',
                scope: {
                    stream_webcam: '=webcam',
                    stream_type: '@type'
                },


                controller: function($scope, $sce) {

                    $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
                      var url;
                      if ($scope.stream_webcam.webcam_domain == 'twitcam') {
                        url = 'templates/' + $scope.stream_webcam.webcam_domain + '.php';
                      } else if ... {
                        url = 'templates/second.html';
                      } else ...
                      return url;
                    }
...
```

How to put templates in my angularjs folder directive ?

Answer (score 0):

**Pass  HTML  template file  to directive**
you can pass by templateUrl . you can give CSS file link in your html file itself as usual.

```
app.directive('contactTable', ['$window',,
function($window) {

    return {
        scope: {
            contact: "=",

        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'contactTableController',
        templateUrl: **your folder**+ '/contact-table-template.html', 
        link    :  function ($scope, element, attrs){               

            //your logic and dom access goes here

            });

        }
    };
}
]);
```

Comment: This approach has one problem - it repeats the CSS in the directive template as many times as you include the directive on the page. You can dynamically insert the CSS file URL in the head section from the directive code. This gives you a chance to insert the CSS only once no matter how many times the directive is included in the page.

Comment: angular.element("#PopupView").css({"width": "56%", "position": "absolute", "left":$scope.x-100 , "top":$scope.y+$scope.height+10});
         angular.element(".arrow").css({"left": 120});

Comment: as above you can access DOM in your link function and apply CSS what you what want as per you conditions